# Pow.cx Rails Assets Not Loading (IOError: Closed Stream)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rack-pow

Assets are timing out for my Rails app served locally through Pow. When I visit an asset's url directly (eg. '/assets/home.css') I'm presented with this error:

```
{
    "name":"IOError",
    "message":"closed stream",
    "stack":"/Users/XXX/Library/Application/ Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:158:in `close'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:158:in `ensure in handle'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:158:in `handle'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:99:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in start'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `each'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `block in start'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `loop'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `start'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
    /Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'"
}
```

I'm using Pow 0.4.0, Rack 1.4.5 and Rails 3.2.12.

I've tried restarting the Pow site, restarting Pow, uninstalling and reinstalling Pow, and restarting my machine.

Comment: reformat the error, it's one long line

Comment: I fixed it, but I'm not sure how or when. Sorry.

Comment: did you try upgrading node?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to update node.js. If you installed via Homebrew, you can use:

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
npm update npm -g
```

This will update Homebrew and Node Package Manager.